# Proving an inequality based on condition number.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

[image]

I was trying to prove this inequality, by taking $K(A) = ||A|| ||A^{-1}||$ and also the error $A(x  -\hat{x})  =e$, I am thinking how to get those terms, estimates?  any help in ideas to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to get from $Ax=b$ and $\hat{A}\hat{x}=b$ to
$$
\frac{\|x-\hat{x}\|}{\|x\|}\leq\|I-\hat{A}^{-1}A\|.
$$

Now the rest is a bit more technical. Let $\hat{A}:=A+E$.
We have
$$\tag{1}
I-\hat{A}^{-1}A=\hat{A}^{-1}(\hat{A}-A)=(A+E)^{-1}E.
$$
From $A(A+E)^{-1}=(A+E-E)(A+E)^{-1}=I-E(A+E)^{-1}$, we have
$$
(A+E)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}E(A+E)^{-1},
$$
so with $\|A^{-1}\|\|E\|<1$, we get
$$
\|(A+E)^{-1}\|\leq \|A^{-1}\|-\|A^{-1}\|\|E\|\|(A+E)^{-1}\|\implies
\|(A+E)^{-1}\|\leq\frac{\|A^{-1}\|}{1-\|A^{-1}\|\|E\|}.
$$
Putting this back to (1) gives
$$
\|I-\hat{A}^{-1}A\|\leq\frac{\|A^{-1}\|\|E\|}{1-\|A^{-1}\|\|E\|}
=\frac{\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|}{1-\|A^{-1}\|\|E\|}\frac{\|E\|}{\|A\|}.
$$
Now just plug back $E=\hat{A}-A$.